# how to read an excel file opened with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have to read some sheets in excel files that can be opened during the execution of the program. Furthermore I must have the possibility to modify them even if they are opened by python. I noticed that the command is not enough:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r"filename")
```

Should I use other packages?

Comment: You are asking for guidance, but your question is not precise enough. See the doc for how to read specific sheets using [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), modify whatever you want, then use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to write data to an excel file.

Comment: If my excel is opened? Python give an error.

Comment: If the file is open, has to be closed. Pandas does not keep the file open (closes after reading), but excel does. Using python `open()` you should use context manager (`with` statement)  or close the file explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

to write excel file via pandas DataFrame is quite convenient. You can just use read_excel or to_excel in batch mode. 
if you want to some advanced mode, for examples,  write several sheets in one excel file. Pandas has already support it.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```

If you want to to operate at the excel engine level, then you has to directly import those excel lib and use their functional directly. Here is some excel engine pandas supported.
     openpyxl: version 2.4 or higher is required
     xlsxwriter
     xlwt

[Here is the pandas excel IO reference.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-excel-writer)

Answer (score 0):

To read an excel file in pandas requires just couple of lines of code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx", sep="separator")
df
```

**Note** : Separator attribute is required when you do not have a default separator (default is ',') in  your input file. For example, if your input file is separated by ';' then you have to mention the separator attribute with value as ';'.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one parameter named `sheet_name` in `pd.read_excel()` mehtod.

You can do that like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx", sheet_name = "name_of_excel_sheet")
```

Hope it helps